# Swift Remote Config: fetchAndActivate does not update local config

Tags: swift, firebase-remote-config

I am getting started with RemoteConfig on iOS with Swift and followed the tutorial to get started. I have developer mode enabled and tested the updating of config values via the Firebase console. However, the update values never get synced with the local config values.

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    syncRemoteConfig()
}

fileprivate func syncRemoteConfig() {
    let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()

    #if DEBUG
        let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
        settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
        remoteConfig.configSettings = settings
    #endif

    remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate { (status, error) in

        let posts = remoteConfig.configValue(forKey: "posts").jsonValue as! [[String: AnyObject]]
        print(posts) // <== Always print the previous data

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

       //status always prints status.successUsingPreFetchedData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `pod update` to at least Firebase 6.25.0.

It fixed a [race condition bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4740) in which the `minimumFetchInterval` might not have been applied before the fetch.